# Apollo server context is undefined

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

After upgrading to Apollo v4, following the migration guide, I used to have a working project.

Now, the context is undefined.

```
const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
  listen: { port: 3000 },
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    try {
      const { token } = req.headers

      console.log(`Token: ${token}`)

      return { token }
    } catch {
      return {}
    }
  },
})
```

Changing to

```
return { context: { token } }
```

Does't not help.

Here, context is **undefined**

```
export const myAuthChecker: AuthChecker<MyContext> = ({ context: { token } }) => {
  if (token) {
    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

What am I missing?

Minimal reproducible example https://github.com/skhaz/graphql-auth

Comment: you must return `return { context: { token: '123'} }`

Comment: I have changed to `return { context: { token } }` and got the same error: "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')",

Comment: return it always, also inside catch block

Comment: Same error. (And I was already passing the token in the headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your package and fixed your issue.

You have to update your tsconfig with at least this target version:

```
"target": "es2018",
```